# Print a newline in a for loop when ever i equals to the multiples of 2

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I print a newline in a `for` loop whenever `i` is equal to a multiple of 2?

for example:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
  for j in range(0, 10):
    print('Hello')
    ##Print a newline when i equals to 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10
    ##if(i == 2):
      ##print('\n')
```

Comment: make a condition for `i`, like `(i mod 2)==0` for example

Answer (score 5):

The most common way to check divisbilty by a number is to check for its modulus being 0.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
  for j in range(0, 10):
    if not i % 2: # same as i % 2 == 0
        print('\n')
```

As an aside, to write a platform dependent newline, you can replace `print('\n')` with `os.write(os.linesep)` (of course `import os` at the top).

Comment: Call me finicky but `not i % 2` doesn't feel too natural (in the sense readability)

Comment: just a personal preference, but i felt that some people wouldn't be a huge fan of it so i put the comment there for the benefit of OP

Comment: @outlyer That was my first thought as well

Comment: I agree that the explicit `expr == 0` form is a _lot_ more readable than `not expr` if `expr` isn't boolean. OTOH, I have been known to use the second form myself, being an old C & assembler programmer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the general solution if the list is not a list of integers necessarily, using `enumerate`.

```
l=['a','b','c']
for ind, ii in enumerate(l):
    print ii
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        print '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to process other values than 2,4,6 and 8, you can pass a step value as a third argument to range() function:

```
for i in range(2,10,2):
    print("\n")
```

In this way, it will print all the numbers between 2 and 10 (not including 10) "stepping 2 steps" at a time.

If you need to process other values than that, stick with chris answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mod 2, then print. usually i % 2.